# How to know if docker is already logged in to a docker registry server

Tags: docker

I'm not sure if I have already logged in to a docker registry in cmd line by using cmd: docker login. How can you test or see whether you are logged in or not, without trying to push?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question? do you want to know if you are logged in on a terminal? why not run **%docker images** command in the terminal and see if your images show up?

Comment: I want to know whether I am logged in to dockerhub registry in terminal. I thought the images are local, so it will just show the local images, not the dockerhub images.

Comment: I believe once you are logged into docker, you are connected to your dockerhub registry. I don't think there is a separate login

Comment: `docker info | grep Username ` this should display your current docker user. Hope helps

Comment: Question https://stackoverflow.com/q/61098378/1548275 is related to this. If a credential helper is in use, the status can be queried via helper.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

**Edit 2020**

Referring back to the (*closed*) [github](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15466) issue, where it is pointed out, there is no actual session or state;

> docker login actually isn't creating any sort of persistent session, it is only storing the user's credentials on disk so that when authentication is required it can read them to login

As others have pointed out, an `auths` entry/node is added to the `~/.docker/config.json` file (this also works for *private* registries) after you succesfully login:

```
{
    "auths": {
            "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
    },
    ...
```

When logging out, this entry is then removed:

```
$ docker logout
Removing login credentials for https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

Content of docker `config.json` after:

```
{
    "auths": {},
    ...
```

This file can be parsed by your script or code to check your login status.

#### Alternative method (re-login)

You can login to docker with `docker login <repository>`

```
$ docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If 
you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to 
create one.
Username:
```

If you are already logged in, the prompt will look like:

```
$ docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If 
you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to 
create one.
Username (myusername):        # <-- "myusername"
```

For the original explanation for the `~/.docker/config.json`, check [question: how can I tell if I'm logged into a private docker registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608467/how-can-i-tell-if-im-logged-in-to-a-private-docker-registry?noredirect=1#comment60864096_36608467)

Comment: The last link talks about checking the contents of `~/.docker/config.json`.

Comment: `docker info` is apparently unreliable even for _index.docker.io_. Currently logged in alright and only see the `Registry` entry, no `Username`.

Comment: docker info is not showing Username anymore. I am on Windows, with docker version 18.05.0-ce.

Comment: What if a script needs to check?

Comment: This only works for the main docker hub, I think. Authing to any other repo you'll have to check your config.json file.

Comment: @duane That is what Dusan refers to in the first comment; it's the post I linked in the bottom of my original post that refers to the `config.json` entry. @Teekin The link I added in my initial post 4 years ago (See bottom), refers to a similar question that contains several scripting solutions. Did you check those?

Comment: docker logout doesn't empty the "auths" entry in configjson, at least it doesn't for me

Comment: That file will be populated even if you had an unsuccessful login.

Comment: @Shōgun8 there simply is no other way at the moment of writing, there are also alternatives mentioned if you do not want to check the file.

Comment: @Fransesco, so the answer is that there is no way to check. This certainly doesn't work because this file stays populated indefinitely until you actively perform `docker logout`. But just because the file is populated with a variable does not mean that you are logged in.

Comment: With docker 1.6.2, I found it in `~/.dockercfg`.

Answer (score 59):

I use one of the following two ways for this check:

#### 1: View config.json file:

In case you are logged in to "private.registry.com" you will see an entry for the same as following in `~/.docker/config.json`:

```
"auths": {
    "private.registry.com": {
        "auth": "gibberishgibberishgibberishgibberishgibberishgibberish"
    }
 }
```

#### 2: Try docker login once again:

If you are trying to see if you already have an active session with private.registry.com, try to login again:

```
bash$ docker login private.registry.com
Username (logged-in-user):
```

If you get an output like the above, it means `logged-in-user` already had an active session with `private.registry.com`. If you are just prompted for username instead, that would indicate that there's no active session.

Answer (score 40):

You can do the following command to see the username you are logged in with and the registry used:

```
docker system info | grep -E 'Username|Registry'
```

Comment: Im logged into a private registry bu this shows for info "Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/". Not accurate or reliable

Comment: Does not work for private repos

Answer (score 17):

The answers here so far are not so useful:

- `docker info` no longer provides this info
- `docker logout` is a major inconvenience - unless you already know the credentials and can easily re-login
- `docker login` response seems quite unreliable and not so easy to parse by the program

My solution that worked for me builds on [@noobuntu's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36022892/314056#comment59697215_36022892): I figured that if I already known the image that I want to pull, but I'm not sure if the user is already logged in, I can do this:

```
try pulling target image
-> on failure:
   try logging in
   -> on failure: throw CannotLogInException
   -> on success:
      try pulling target image
      -> on failure: throw CannotPullImageException
      -> on success: (continue)
-> on success: (continue)
```

Comment: This is by far the best stratgy: just try a pull, if it fails then it is not logged in (the rest of the logic you have will depend on each use case, but the first try is universally applicable).

Comment: However someone pointed out on https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15466 that there are many reasons for failure, not just login issue, yet docker exit status does not allow to differentiate reason for failure. It's still better than the other solutions, but a full solution would require a patch to docker.

Answer (score 17):

The docker cli credential scheme is unsurprisingly uncomplicated, just take a look:

`cat ~/.docker/config.json`

```
{
  "auths": {
    "dockerregistry.myregistry.com": {},
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
```

This exists on Windows (use `Get-Content ~\.docker\config.json`) and you can also poke around the credential tool which also lists the username ... and I think you can even retrieve the password

`. "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-credential-wincred.exe" list`

```
{"https://index.docker.io/v1/":"kcd"}
```

Comment: On windows you can see only the username, the password is stored in credentials manager (control panel)

Comment: I guess I will spoil the surprise... `docker-credential-wincred.exe <store|get|erase|list|version>` which means you can `get` your password

Comment: That cat command should use linux path separators: cat ~/.docker/config.json . This may seem a nit-pick to some, but other readers might just copy/paste it and try it, and not realize readily that the "no such file or directory" error is due to this. :-)

Comment: @charliearehart you underestimate my laziness, I was using the `cat` alias in Powershell... updated to include both

Answer (score 8):

My AWS ECR build-script has:

```
ECR_HOSTNAME="${ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com"
TOKEN=$(jq -r '.auths["'$ECR_HOSTNAME'"]["auth"]' ~/.docker/config.json)
curl --fail --header "Authorization: Basic $TOKEN" https://$ECR_HOSTNAME/v2/
```

If accessing ECR fails, a login is done:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region ${REGION} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin https://$ECR_HOSTNAME
```

For this to work, a proper Docker credential store cannot be used. Default credentials store of `~/.docker/config.json` is assumed.

Comment: This is one of the few that works and works well with private repos (like AWS). Just depends on `jq`, `docker` and `curl`. Thanks!

Comment: This only works if you're not using a credential store.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions In my answer I wrote "For this to work, a proper Docker credential store cannot be used." Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 7):

For private registries, nothing is shown in `docker info`. However, the logout command will tell you if you were logged in:

```
 $ docker logout private.example.com
 Not logged in to private.example.com
```

(Though this will force you to log in again.)

Answer (score 7):

Just checked, today it looks like this:

```
$ docker login
Authenticating with existing credentials...
Login Succeeded
```

*NOTE: this is on a macOS with the latest version of Docker CE, docker-credential-helper - both installed with homebrew.*

Comment: this is how to login

Comment: yes, but if you're not logged in you will be prompted for a UN/PW. If you are ALREADY logged in, it will simply refresh your session as above; notice the phrase "existing credentials".

Comment: Fair enough; I was only considering programmatic solutions, but that's no what the op asked.

Comment: @Shōgun8, the `docker-credential-helper` makes it so you really don't have to think about it. If you're looking for programmatic solutions to this it's likely something else is wrong. Make sure you won't need programmatic solutions by using tools to help manage credentials. #forwardengineering

Comment: @ todd_dsm, Well I'm not trying avoid programmatic solutions; on the contrary I am searching for programmatic solutions. Also that program does not address the problem.

Answer (score 6):

At least in "Docker for Windows" you can see if you are logged in to docker hub over the UI. Just right click the docker icon in the windows notification area:
[image: Docker Logged in]

Comment: what about the docker versions without the GUI? or non-windows ?

Comment: Then you have to use one of the approaches from the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a simple `true/false` value, you can pipe your `docker.json` to `jq`.

```
is_logged_in() {
  cat ~/.docker/config.json | jq -r --arg url "${REPOSITORY_URL}" '.auths | has($url)'
}

if [[ "$(is_logged_in)" == "false" ]]; then
  # do stuff, log in
fi
```

Comment: You can have `jq` return a proper exit code and then you don't need to do string comparisons: `is_logged_in() { jq -e --arg url ${ADDRESS} '.auths | has($url)' ~/.docker/config.json > /dev/null; }; if is_logged_in; then ...`

Comment: This only shows that you _have_ logged in, not whether or not you _are_ logged in. This returns true even if the session has expired.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux if you have the `secretservice` enabled via the `credsStore` option in your `~/.docker/config.json` like below:

```
"credsStore": "secretservice",
```

then you will not see the credentials in the `config.json`. Instead you need to query the credentials using the `docker-credential-desktop`, see the below answer for more details:

[How to know if docker is already logged in to a docker registry server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022892/how-to-know-if-docker-is-already-logged-in-to-a-docker-registry-server)

Answer (score 1):

Use command like below:

```
docker info | grep 'name'

WARNING: No swap limit support
Username: <strong>jonasm2009</strong>
```

Comment: If you are already logged in to a docker registry,just use [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkCxn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkCxn.png) You will see the answer .

Answer (score 1):

On windows you can inspect the login "authorizations" (auths) by looking at this file:
**[USER_HOME_DIR].docker\config.json**

Example: 
**c:\USERS\YOUR_USERANME.docker\config.json**

It will look something like this for windows credentials

```
{
"auths": {
    "HOST_NAME_HERE": {},
    "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
},
"HttpHeaders": {
    "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.09.0 (windows)"
},
"credsStore": "wincred",
"stackOrchestrator": "swarm"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Container Registry (ACR) following works as a login-check:

```sh
registry="contosoregistry.azurecr.io"
curl -v --header "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" https://$registry/v2/_catalog
```

If access token has expired, a HTTP/401 will be returned.

Options for getting an access token are from `~/.docker/config.json` or requesting one from `https://$registry/oauth2/token` using a refresh token stored into Docker credStore: `echo $registry | docker-credential-desktop get`.

More information about refresh tokens and access tokens are at ACR integration [docs](https://github.com/Azure/acr/blob/main/docs/AAD-OAuth.md#calling-post-oauth2token-to-get-an-acr-access-token).

Answer (score 1):

To many answers above is just about how to check login status manually. To do it from command line you can use the command below.

```bash
cat ~/.docker/config.json | jq '.auths["<MY_REGISTRY_HOSTNAME>"]' -e > /dev/null &&  echo "OK" ||  echo "ERR"
```

1. Ensure you have jq command in your local. To test that run `jq --version` command. If you can't get an version output follow the directions from here to install it https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/
2. Replace <MY_REGISTRY_HOSTNAME> with your registry address.
3. When you run it returns `OK` if you successfully login already otherwise `ERR`

**NOTE:** if you used a credential helper to login (e.g. google cloud auth tool for container registry) replace `.auths` keyword with `.credHelpers`

Comment: I like the intent of this solution, but this doesn't cover the case where you've logged in previously, and for whatever reason, those credentials have expired.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Christian, best to try operation first then login only if necessary. Problem is that "if necessary" is not that obvious to do robustly. One approach is to compare the stderr of the docker operation with some strings that are known (by trial and error). For example,

```
try "docker OPERATION"
if it failed: 
    capture the stderr of "docker OPERATION"
    if it ends with "no basic auth credentials": 
        try docker login
    else if it ends with "not found":
        fatal error: image name/tag probably incorrect
    else if it ends with <other stuff you care to trap>:
        ...
    else:
        fatal error: unknown cause

try docker OPERATION again
if this fails: you're SOL!
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a powershell command to check if you have previously logged into the registry, making use of the file `$HOME/.docker/config.json` that others have mentioned:

```
(Get-Content $HOME/.docker/config.json | ConvertFrom-Json).auths.PSobject.Properties.name -Contains "<registry_url>"
```

This returns a True / False boolean, so can use as follows:

```
if ((Get-Content $HOME/.docker/config.json | ConvertFrom-Json).auths.PSobject.Properties.name -Contains "<registry_url>" ) {
    Write-Host Already logged into docker registry
} else {
    Write-Host Logging into docker registry
    docker login
}
```

If you want it to not fail if the file doesn't exist you need an extra check:

```
if ( (-Not (Test-Path $HOME/.docker/config.json)) -Or (-Not (Get-Content $HOME/.docker/config.json | ConvertFrom-Json).auths.PSobject.Properties.name -Contains "<registry_url>") )
{
    Write-Host Already logged into docker registry
} else {
    Write-Host Logging into docker registry
    docker login
}
```

I chose to use the -Not Statements because for some reason when you chain a command after a failed condition with `-And` instead of `-Or` the command errors out.