# How can I tell if I'm logged in to a private Docker registry from a script?

Tags: docker

How can I tell whether or not I'm logged in to a private Docker registry server from a script?  In other words, has `docker login some.registry.com` been run successfully (and is still valid)?

Note: I'm asking about an arbitrary private registry, not the `docker.io` registry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know if docker is already logged in to a docker registry server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022892/how-to-know-if-docker-is-already-logged-in-to-a-docker-registry-server)

Comment: No, that only works for the docker.io registry.

Comment: You are absolutely right. From [github issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15466): `docker login actually isn't creating any sort of persistent session, it is only storing the user's credentials on disk so that when authentication is required it can read them to login`; although this is from aug 2015 and I haven't looked in-depth, it's a _long_ time ago (but last comment from jan 2016 and still an open issue). Doing a pull on the registry just to check seems kind of backward.

Answer (score 24):

if docker login worked, you will find a `.docker` folder on your home directory (`~/.docker/`), with a `config.json` file with credentials in it.

otherwise you would get an error login in.

Note: docker determine what credentials to use by looking at the registry name:

if you do

`docker pull myregistry.com/myimage:tag`

docker will look if you're logged in, and if not will check if you have the credentials for the registry `myregistry.com` and login with those.

If not you will get a permission error

Comment: Unfortunately in this case `docker pull` exists with status 1, so there's no way to distinguish "not logged in" from all the other `docker pull` failure modes.  So it seems I'm down to parsing `config.json` or the `docker pull` output, and hoping the format doesn't change in a future Docker release.

Comment: not sure what you mean here: if i `docker pull` without being logged in, I get a `Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.XXXXXXXX.com/v2/base/manifests/dev: no basic auth credentials`

Comment: use `docker -D pull ...` to debug

Comment: I'm trying to do this from a script.  (I just clarified this in the question.)  So I'd need to capture the output from `docker pull`, check if I got a message like the one you mention, and hope that the message doesn't change in a future Docker release.

Alternatively I could parse `config.json` but again the format of this file could change in a future Docker release, so this isn't a great solution either.

Comment: why don't you look at the exit code of docker login? 
`docker login -u <user_name> -p <password> -e <email> private.registry.com` and then `echo $?` for the exit code. or simply `docker login -u <user_name> -p <password> -e <email> private.registry.com || echo "that didn't work"`

Comment: other option from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022892/how-to-know-if-docker-is-already-logged-in-to-a-docker-registry-server?lq=1

use docker info to see what you're logged in to

Comment: I'm trying to avoid running `docker login` if it's already been run successfully.

Also the question you linked has already been suggested above, and as I explained, that answer only works for the `docker.io` registry, not other registries.

Comment: This gets murkier if using (for example) ASW ECR. the credentials you login with expires every 12 hours, so if just looking at the `config.json` for example it will LOOK like all is ok, but it won't be. Only way to check is to try some operation, but then as stated above the error code does not really tell you WHAT went wrong (might be auth, might not be).

Comment: to check ecr login use ` `aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1` `

Comment: Does not actually test if you are successfully logged in or not. It displays that text even you only ever attempted a login.

Comment: @Shōgun8 if you successfully logged in before, you will find the file on your system. Now that doesn't mean you are logged in, but Docker will log you in using that file automatically if you are not logged in. However it is true that it does not guaranty that login will be successful: if credentials changed between the time you  successfully logged in the first time and the time you run a command, the login will fail.

Answer (score 17):

This is a bit hacky, but it works in most of the cases for me:

```
if ! grep -q "my.private.registry.com" ~/.docker/config.json ; then
    docker login "my.private.registry.com"
fi
```

Basically, you search if there is a record of "my.private.registry.com" in `~/.docker/config.json`. However, if the session is expired, this check won't catch it.

Comment: Works for official dockerhub, too if you replace my.private-registry with "index.docker.io". Thank you, I needed to check it in a shell script, so thats exactly what I needed.

Comment: Does not actually test if you are successfully logged in or not. It displays that text even you only ever attempted a login.

Answer (score 12):

If you are constrained to examining your local system, it's impossible to know!

... The only way to be sure the credentials docker has stored are still valid is to perform an operation that will cause them to be presented to the registry, and to see if the registry accepts them.

If you want to use the docker CLI to get an answer, then you could use @matanper suggestion of "login again" which will complete automatically if you still have valid credentials.

Another way is to try to pull an image known *not to exist*, which will show different error message when logged in or not e.g.

```
# NO VALID LOGIN:

$ docker pull 999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/this/image:does_not_exist
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for 999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/this/image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

versus

```
# WITH VALID LOGIN:

$ docker pull 999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/this/image:does_not_exist
Error response from daemon: manifest for 999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/this/image:does_not_exist not found
```

(presume that you didn't want to `pull` because you don't want any delay or large data tranfser, so the above method is still 'ok')

In the past, when docker always stored credentials in `~/.docker/config.json` (or equivalent for your OS), you could parse that file to get the currently stored credentials and then run a [simple list operation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-repositories) using `curl` or similar. However, recent docker versions store the credentials in host OS specific stores (e.g. the keychain on Mac OS X) so that is no longer a portable methodology. If portability is not important, you could still try something like that - the hash in `config.json` is just the base64 encoded username & password, separated by a colon, as is standard for HTTP basic auth e.g. on linux, with `jq` to parse JSON, and `base64` to decode base64:

```
$  cat ~/.docker/config.json  | jq -r '.auths["registry.example.com"].auth' | base64 -d

username:password
```

So, completing that with a registry list operation using `curl`:

```
REGISTRY="registry.example.com"

CREDENTIALS="$(cat ~/.docker/config.json | jq -r ".auths[\"${REGISTRY}\"].auth" | base64 -d)"

curl -sSf --max-time 3 --user "${CREDENTIALS}" "https://${REGISTRY}/v2/_catalog"
```

will return exit code zero, and a JSON response if the CREDENTIALS are good; or a non-zero exit code if not

```
{
  "repositories": [
    "jamesjj/test-image",
    "jamesjj/other-image",
    ...
    ...
}
```

NOTE: When parsing the JSON, the registry address key may or may not include the schema `https://`, depending on how the original login was performed, so `cat ~/.docker/config.json | jq -r ".auths[\"${REGISTRY}\"].auth" | base64 -d)"`
... may need to be:
`cat ~/.docker/config.json | jq -r ".auths[\"https://${REGISTRY}\"].auth" | base64 -d)"`

Answer (score 12):

I believe the error message will vary by registry implementation. However, my own technique is to pull an image that doesn't exist and parse any error message:

```
$!/bin/sh
repo="$1"
msg=$(docker pull ${repo}/missing:missing 2>&1)
case "$msg" in
  *"requested access to the resource is denied"*|*"pull access denied"*)
    echo "Logged out";;
  *"manifest unknown"*|*"not found"*)
    echo "Logged in, or read access for anonymous allowed";;
  *"Pulling from"*)
    echo "Missing image was not so missing after all?";;
  *) 
    echo "Unknown message: $msg";;
esac
```

This has been tested with the docker standalone registry and docker_auth. You'll want to test with registries that you may encounter.

If your registry server allows anonymous pulls and you want to verify a push is possible, you can create a dummy empty image and replace the pull with a push of that image. E.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
repo=$1
# note, I do not like the "." here, better to change it to an empty directory
# see "mktemp" for an option if you cannot make your own empty directory somewhere
docker build -t "${repo}/empty:test" -f - . <<EODF
FROM scratch
EODF
msg=$(docker push "${repo}/empty:test" 2>&1)
rc=$?
if [ "$rc" = "0" ]; then
  echo "Access granted to push"
else
  case "$msg" in
    *"requested access to the resource is denied"*)
      echo "Access denied";;
    *) 
      echo "Unknown error message: $msg";;
  esac
fi
```

Comment: Awarded bounty as this was the only suggestion with both a server query and actual scripting. It is sad the docker developers do not consider these things in the cli important.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I believe the API only checks access when you do an actual push or pull. The credentials can get fairly granular with different access to different repos. But an extension could likely be made to verify a login itself is valid.

Comment: I'm using a one liner based on this answer now (does not work for publicly visible registries):
```
DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled docker manifest inspect ${repo}/missing 2>&1 | grep -q "^no such manifest: "
```
fails if not logged in, if you want to inverse the truthiness pass -v to grep

Answer (score 3):

This is a little hacky, I think until docker will have a command to check login, there won't be any good solution.
You can in your bash script try to login with timeout of x seconds, if you aren't logged in the command will try to prompt for username and then it will timeout with status `124`. If you are indeed logged in, it will just log you in again using the save credentials and continue with status `0`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
timeout -s SIGKILL 3s docker login some.registry.com >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
   echo Logged In!
else
   echo Not logged in...
fi
```

Comment: Reports "Not logged in" whether you are logged in or not

Answer (score 3):

This is somewhat old, but I needed the same thing today. I found
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022892/how-to-know-if-docker-is-already-logged-in-to-a-docker-registry-server) first, and from that, I derived this, which I think answers the OP's question directly:

```sh
# try to login. If you are logged in, it exits happily. If you aren't, it prompts
# for credentials. By redirecting stdin to /dev/null, we guarantee this fails
docker login ${MY_REG} < /dev/null >& /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0]; then
  echo "Already logged in"
else
  echo "Login required"
fi
```

If `MY_REG` is unset, it will check against docker.io. Otherwise, against the registry you set.

I do understand that there is a difference between storing credentials and authenticating with the registry, and perhaps that's an important nuance in the OP's use case. In my case, I just wanted to know the former. If the latter is important, then by all means, pull an image.

Comment: Wonderful, I've been looking for a solution that would work for my script for a long time, and this was it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can parse `.docker/config.json` and try to manually connect to each registry specified in the file. The file contains the registry address and encoded username and password so you can script this process. You can do that using a library like [docker-registry-client](https://github.com/yodle/docker-registry-client).

```
pip install docker-registry-client
```

And then:

```
import base64
import docker_registry_client
import json
import os.path

def get_authed_registries():
  result = []
  config_path = os.path.expanduser("~/.docker/config.json")
  if not os.path.isfile(config_path):
    print("No docker config")
    return []

  docker_config = json.load(open(config_path))

  for registry, auth in docker_config.get("auths", {}).items():
    username, password = base64.b64decode(auth["auth"]).decode("utf-8").split(":", 1)
    if not registry:
      registry = "https://index.docker.io/v1/"
    if not registry.startswith("http"):
      registry = "https://" + registry
    try:
      rc = docker_registry_client.DockerRegistryClient(registry, username=username, password=password)
      result.append(registry)
    except Exception, e:
      print(registry, "failed:", e)

  return result


get_authed_registries()
```

A few caveats:

- This may fail if you're using a [credential store](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store).
- Tested on Python 2.7. Might need small adjustments for Python 3.
- This code works for authentication, but any further actions on the registry fail. You will need to strip away API version (`/v1`, `/v2`, etc.) from the host name for that.
- The code assumes all registries are HTTPS (unless specified otherwise in `config.json`)
- An even more correct version will probably strip away anything but the hostname and try both v1 and v2.

That said, I was able to get a list of logged-in registries and it correctly ignored expired ECR login.

Answer (score -1):

When you do the

```
Docker login <private registry> -u <user> -p <password>
```

command from your terminal, you will have a response: (stored in $?)

```
0
Login Succeeded
```

if you were successful.

In your shell script, you could just look at the response you're receiving, if it does not equal 0, you've failed to login.

```
sudo docker login <registry> -u <uname> -p <password>
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo Login failed!
else
    echo Login OK!
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, which is how to tell if you're currently logged in or not.

Comment: Did you not say "see if the login command was successful" and, that it was part of a script?

Comment: although this has an issue, when docker is used with a proxy https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2097