# pushing docker image to Docker hub in a shell script using Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am getting error pushing the docker image:

```
denied: requested access to the resource is denied

unauthorized: authentication required


script returned exit code 1
```

The Jenkinsfile stage:

```
        stage('upload docker') {
            steps {
                sh "./upload_docker.sh"
            }
        }
```

In the upload_docker file:

```
docker push username/repo:3
```

I added the user to the docker group.

I added Jenkins to the docker group.

I added Jenkins to the user group and vice versa.

I changed the permission of the docker config file to allow all.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) to docker hub before you can push your image to it.

Comment: I logged in from ubuntu user.

Comment: Check if you're logged in Jenkins, try the following [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022892/how-to-know-if-docker-is-already-logged-in-to-a-docker-registry-server)

Comment: It worked! I logged in to the instance and I changed the user to Jenkins user. then I added the credentials again. but is it the best way to do that? or should I follow the method below?

Answer (score 2):

In order to push docker image to a private registry, you will need to:

1. Install `docker-workflow` plugin.
2. Create `Username/password` credential.
3. Wrap your code to push to docker registry like

```
docker.withRegistry('https://registry.example.com', 'credentials-id') {

    def customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}")

    /* Push the container to the custom Registry */
    customImage.push()
}
```

Reference from Jenkins [docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#custom-registry)