# How to retrieve password from docker credStore?

Tags: docker

I'm using `docker-credential-desktop` to store my passwords for my remote docker registry. From what I understand this command should retrieve my password and username for the registry

```
docker-credential-desktop get "https://index.docker.io/v1/"
```

But when I run it i get this error

```
Usage: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker-credential-desktop.exe <store|get|erase|list|version>
```

I couldn't find the right format for the command in the docker docs. Is this the right format or am i missing something?

Answer (score 21):

**Windows**

Execute `docker-credential-desktop.exe list`, you'll get a list of domains:
`{"docker.domain.com":"username","nexus.domain.com:3131":"username"}`

Execute `docker-credential-desktop.exe get`, then input the domain (such as `docker.domain.com`) , input CTRL+Z immediately after, and press Enter :

```
  docker-credential-desktop.exe get
  docker.domain.com^Z[Enter key]
```

**Linux / MacOS**

Execute `docker-credential-desktop list`, you'll get a list of domains:
`{"docker.domain.com":"username","nexus.domain.com:3131":"username"}`

Use `docker-credential-desktop get`, and pass the domain (such as `docker.domain.com`) via pipe from `echo` and press Enter:

```
  echo docker.domain.com | docker-credential-desktop get
```

The response contains the secret:
`{"ServerURL":"docker.domain.com","Username":"username","Secret":"secret"}`

Comment: On Mac, Ctrl+Z suspends the process; however, it looks like you can do `echo <yourdomain> | docker-credential-desktop get`